# Странное поведение: nth-child(x)

Tags: html, css

Товарищи объясните почему так себя ведет свойство :nth-child?

CSS:

```
section {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Как видим из кода выделяем бордером 2ой по счету section, а выделяется первый. Если убрать <header></header> то всё нормально, почему так? section и header разные субстанции разве нет?

Фиддл для удобства: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/jz4Hf/

Comment: @Олег Б, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Псевдокласс `:nth-child( Х )` дословно переводится как "который является дочерним по отношению к `contained block`'у и соответствует правилу Х". В данном случае и `header` и `section` являются дочерними по отношению к `body` и воспринимаются как члены одного набора.

Для того чтобы правило Х сработало только к тем элементам (одного типа), к классу которого используется псевдокласс, необходимо сам псевдокласс заменить на `:nth-of-type( X )`.

[Переработанный Ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/jz4Hf/3/).

Comment: Пока писал ответ, приняли другой :/

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробное пояснение!!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! В своё время тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Comment: Было неожиданно для меня, благодаря вам теперь я знаю!

Comment: и я тоже =)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jz4Hf/2/ -  нужно блоки, для которых используешь nth-child, обрамлять парентом